# There is an "and" clause on Realm Java?

Tags: java, android, realm

I am currently using the 87.1 of Realm version for Android, and I did not find any **and** clause, just **or** clause.

Here is my issue:

I have a table Products and an AutoCompleteTextView where the user will search for his product while some suggestions it will dropdown in a list. As figure below.

[image: App with autocomplete]

Let’s say that Products has the values:

```
{ "Product 1", "Product 2", "Product 3", "Product 4", "Product 5" }
```

Those are simple names just for this question.

What I am trying to achieve is when the user types “Prod 5” the suggestion be “Product 5”. That would make it simple for the user to find his product, instead of typing all the name of it.

So using this template for filtering the data for AutoCompleteTextView https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/646, in the performRealmFiltering method, I have tried this:

```
RealmQuery realmQuery = RealmResults<Products>.where();
String[] split = String.valueOf(constraint).split(" ");
int i = 1;
for(String part : split) {
    if(split.length == i) {
        realmQuery = realmQuery.contains("ProductDescription", part, Case.INSENSITIVE);
    }
    else
    {
        realmQuery = realmQuery.contains("ProductDescription", part, Case.INSENSITIVE).or();
    }
    i++;
}
return realmQuery.findAll();
```

Obviously that did not properly filtered the data and return all Products, because the **or** should be an **and**.

Therefore, my question is: 
There is an **and** clause in Realm for Java? Or another clause that do the same as **and**, or even another way to achieve this filtering query?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I find a work around for it that works fine.

```
RealmQuery realmQuery = RealmResults<Products>.where();
String[] split = String.valueOf(constraint).split(" ");
for(String part : split) {
    realmQuery = realmQuery.contains("ProductDescription", part, Case.INSENSITIVE);
}
return realmQuery.findAll();
```

I just keep replacing the same query.

However, I did not know why it works yet, so if someone knows why, I will be glad to hear.

Best regards

Comment: `and()` is implicit in the query language, so the above is actually correct: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#logical-operators

Comment: Thanks Christian! 
The Realm support is great